# I need drivers for my Fujitsu fi6130 scanner

Tags: scanner

I really need to find drivers for my scanner Fujitsu fi6130. Running Ubuntu 14.4 LS

Comment: Works for me on MacOS with installing `brew install sane-backends` and Debian Buster with installing `apt install sane` without any additional configuration and `scanimage -L` to list the scanner and `scanimage ...` to scan documents.

Answer (score 0):

Try Vuescan.You can download it from here:

[Vuescan download](http://www.hamrick.com/download.html)

See here for details:

[Vuescan page](http://www.hamrick.com/vuescan/fujitsu_fi_6130.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try this site [Fujitsu fi-6130 Driver](https://fujitsusoftware.com/fujitsu-fi-6130z-driver/)

or Fujitsu fi-6130 document management scanner, Fujitsu fi-6130 customer reviews, Trade ... Windows 7: Notify me when Windows 7 drivers are available from [Fujitsu fi-6130 Software](https://scansnapsoftware.co/fujitsu-fi-6130-software/)